# Recyclerview Layout Manager Get View in Position After Scrolling in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

`Recyclerview` is scrolling with it's `LinearLayoutManager` like that `lm.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, offset)`. How to get the view where in scrolled position before scrolling? The view that will scrolled returning null after scrolling because still not created. I've try `Runnable`, `Observer` and `onLayoutCompleted` but still null. How to get the view?

```
lm.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, offset);

recyclerView.post(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        View v1 = recyclerView.getChildAt(position); // returning null.
        View v2 = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildAt(position); // returning null.
    }
});

recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver()
   .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
       @Override
       public void onGlobalLayout() {
           View v1 = recyclerView.getChildAt(position); // returning null.
           View v2 = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildAt(position); // returning null.
       recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
}});

@Override // in LinearLayoutManager
public void onLayoutCompleted(RecyclerView.State state) {
    super.onLayoutCompleted(state);
    View v1 = recyclerView.getChildAt(position); // returning null.
    View v2 = this.getChildAt(position); // returning null.  
}
```

Comment: `RecyclerView` is creating/reusing views as you scroll - those that are not visible do not exist or are currently assigned to different positions, so trying to `get` them prior to their layout is impossible.

Comment: Yes, you're right but there should be a listener for catching when created scrolled view in position.

Comment: Generally you should never directly modify `RecyclerView` views since their internal state is very volatile. Instead you should modify your data set, call `adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)` and reflect state change inside adapters `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, position)`.

Comment: Why do you want the layout of the item when scrolling? do you want to change the layout of the item when it comes on the screen? when exactly do you want to change the layout and why? please provide more details

Comment: Because I want to emphasise the scrolled item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
View v = lm.getChildAt(position);
lm.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, offset);
v.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // View is ready here.                
});
```

Comment: thansk @Pleaser

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to modify the view content, you should do this:

1. Modify your current model: `itemList.get(position) // and change
   any property here to handle that state`
2. Call `adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)`
3. Make sure you have the right logic on your `ViewHolder` to handle
   this changes and that should modify your `View`

But if you really wanna change things through the `ViewHolder` you can also do this: `recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)` and then:

`if (null != holder) {
   holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_ID) // call any method do you want to
}`

I really recommend the first option, but that's up to you. Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for reply but the holder returning null for outside of screen. As for your first opinion, I don't want to use dataset exept data.